# How to sort Generic List Asc or Desc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, sorting

I have a generic collection of type MyImageClass, and MyImageClass has an boolean property "IsProfile". I want to sort this generic list which IsProfile == true stands at the start of the list.

I have tried this.

```
rptBigImages.DataSource = estate.Images.OrderBy(est=>est.IsProfile).ToList();
```

with the code above the image stands at the last which IsProfile property is true.
But i want it to be at the first index. I need something *Asc or Desc*. Then i did this.

```
rptBigImages.DataSource = estate.Images.OrderBy(est=>est.IsProfile).Reverse.ToList();
```

Is there any easier way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about:

```
estate.Images.OrderByDescending(est => est.IsProfile).ToList()
```

This will order the Images in descending order by the IsProfile Property and then create a new List from the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my unnecessary, i dont know why i didnt take attention the word under OrderBy on the intellisense.

Thanks again

Comment: Is there any other way of just ordering the List instead of creating a new list except Marc's answer

Comment: What reasons would you not want to sort with LINQ or sort with the built in Sort() method?

Answer (score 33):

You can use .OrderByDescending(...) - but note that with the LINQ methods you are creating a new ordered list, not ordering the existing list.

If you have a `List<T>` and want to re-order the **existing** list, then you can use `Sort()` - and you can make it easier by adding a few extension methods:

```
static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(x),selector(y)));
}
static void SortDescending<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(y),selector(x)));
}
```

Then you can use `list.Sort(x=>x.SomeProperty)` and `list.SortDescending(x=>x.SomeProperty)`.

Comment: Thanks Marc, so if i use Linq for ordering, does it mean that it causes a performance loss ?

Comment: Well, in a very small way, but compared to data-binding you'll never notice it.

Comment: This is really helpful.  Could this be extended to also do ThenOrderBy?

Comment: @Ash, not "as is", since it is doing an immediate sort. It would need a bit more glue to do it - more than I can write at this moment...