# How can I create an empty collection from an anonymous collection most elegantly in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If I have an anonymous type created by LINQ

```
var ans = from r in someList where someCondition(r) select new { r.a, r.b };
```

What is the best way to create an empty matching collection so I can move elements to the new collection:

```
var newans = ?
foreach (r in ans) { if (complicated(r)) newans.Add(r); }
```

Is there some way to use Enumerable.Empty<>()?

Comment: I realize the foreach/if could be replaced by more LINQ in my simple example, but my actual problem is more complex and what I really wanted, a LINQ Delete, isn't available.

Comment: Did you search before posting?  This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661663/anonymous-type-collections

Comment: Suggest a search that pulls that up? I searched Google, I searched here, I tried multiple tags and keywords. Not a subject that lends itself to searches. I did try searching on just collection, but missed that question as being related to mine, as internally I wanted something more generic that doesn't handle just List<T> types, but any var variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use the `ans.Where(x => false).ToList()` versions these iterate over all elements, which you don't need; `ans.Take(0).ToList()` is a little better, as this one doesn't actually iterate over the entire list when you're querying over in-memory sequences (LINQ to Objects).

If you are using LINQ to SomethingElse, things are a little problematic, because it might actually execute something like `SELECT TOP(0) * FROM ...` or `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE 1 = 0`. Not good.

So the following helper method will help you:

```
public static class AnonymousTypeExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToEmptyList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}

var newans = ans.ToEmptyList();
```

Having said that, if your only desire is to copy some elements of `ans` into a new list, you're better of with

```
var newans = (from a in ans where isComplicated(a) select a).ToList();
```

or

```
var newans = ans.Where(a => isComplicated(a)).ToList();
```

If you don't need an actual `List<T>`, and an `IEnumerable<T>` is enough, you might get away with omitting the `ToList` altogether. Mind you, every time you foreach over such an enumerable, `Where(a => isComplicated(a))` is executed again and again. The call to `ToList` makes sure you only execute it once.

---

If you don't want this just for `List<T>`, but more general, things get a lot more complicated. For example, should the method return the static type of the `ans` variable or its runtime type? Also, there is no such thing as a "default" version of many collections, apart from blindly calling `new C()`. But that won't work generally. It's not possible to call `new ReadOnlyCollection<T>()`, because it doesn't exist (and the collection would be sealed anyway, so it cannot be filled). And if you're using a HasSet, shouldn't you be using the original's comparer for your empty copy rather than the default comparer?

However, for the simplest case, you could try:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static TCollection AsEmpty<TCollection>(this TCollection source)
        where TCollection : ICollection, new()
    {
        return new TCollection();
    }
}
```

Note that this is a compile-time solution which returns a default collection of the *variable*'s type. If at all possible. For instance `ans = from r in somesource select new { ... }` will have the static type `IEnumerable<...>`. There's no default instance here to create. Also, the runtime type returned by `select` is private to System.Core.dll, doesn't have a default constructor, and is a read-only cursor-like type anyway.

So my opinion on this one is: don't go there. Don't try to over-generalize, stick to simple solutions like ToEmptyList or even better, stick to plain LINQ method chaining.

Comment: That is very nice - seems like the kind of thing the language should have, but can it be genericized to handle when the var ans is not a List<T>?

Comment: This works on any IEnumerable<T> (including LINQ queries), for any T. Or I might not fully understand your question.

Comment: It will convert any IEnumerable<T> to an empty List<T>, but how about creating an empty X<T> for any X? What about

     var v = Default(ans)?

Comment: I've elaborated on that part now. Simply put: don't do that :-)

Comment: +1, great answer. Addresses some coding style suggestions that transcend OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but

```
var newans = from r in ans where false select r;
```

seems like a way to generate the right type of IEnumerable (but not a collection you can 'add' to - you could ToList it).

That said, if you're using LINQ, seems unlikely to have the 'foreach-if-.add' code you have in the question, just

```
var newans = from r in ans where isComplicated(r) select r;
```

or

```
var newans = ans.Where(isComplicated);
```

no?

Answer (score 1):

`var newans = ans.Where(false).ToList()` will do it.

`Enumerable.Empty` can't be used because it's not possible to explicitly pass an anonymous type as a generic argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var newans = ans.ToList();` which will copy every enumerated object into a new list.