# How can I sort variable number of columns with Linq C#?

Tags: c#, sorting

The below code works for sorting two columns (by surname then first name), however I need to sort by a variable number of names (2-5 per entry). Adding another ThenBy split at whitespace causes an out of bounds exception. I understand why, but I was wondering if there is any way around this to get the code to work with Linq or if I need to go some other route. Apologies if this is simple, I'm completely new to C#. I have searched for an answer for a while and cannot find it.

The code below outputs to console:

```
Jimbo Crab
Jonathan Crab
Michael Crab
Steve Cruthers
Barry John
David Johnson
```

Correctly ordered first by surname then by given name.

However the names I need to sort are of varying lengths, i.e:

Barry John
Daniel Johnson James
Steve Davidson Andrew Colins
Lorna Michael

Which should produce:

```
Steve Davidson Andrew Colins
Daniel Johnson James
Barry John
Lorna Michael
```

These need to be sorted in reverse order, so by surname, then given names and finally forename.

Thanks in advance!

```
var listStr = new[] {
    "Barry John", "Steve Cruthers", "Michael Crab", "David Johnson", "Jonathan Crab", "Jimbo Crab"};

     var sorted = listStr
     .OrderBy(s => s.Split(' ')[1])
     .ThenBy(s => s.Split(' ')[0]);

     foreach (var s in sorted)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
```

Comment: hi Goid, can you add a sample of what the data might look like and what result you expect? ([mcve])

Comment: a variable number of names (2-5 per entry) means what? can you tell us more so we will provide what you expected a solution?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171741/ordering-by-index-of-property-in-anonymous-type-declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier and more efficient to split each string once, and then sort using the arrays. Finally you may join the arrays back to strings if you want.

```
var sorted = listStr
    .Select(s => s.Split(' ')) // project string to an array
    .OrderBy(a => a[a.Length - 1]) // order by last element
    .ThenBy(a => a.Length > 2 ? a[1] : a[0]) // then order by middle element
    .ThenBy(a => a[0]) // then order by first element
    .Select(a => String.Join(" ", a)); // project back to a string
```